# $\| \mathbf{A} \|_1 \ne \sum_{i = 1}^{M} \sum_{j = 1}^{N} |a_{i,j}|$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-norms

When I try to derive the formula for $\| \mathbf{A} \|_1$ from the [general definition of a matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) (section "Matrix norms induced by vector norms"), I get $\sum_{i = 1}^{M} \sum_{j = 1}^{N} |a_{i,j}|$?

But my textbook and the same wiki page says that it should be $\max_{1 \leq j \leq M} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} |a_{i,j}|$. How can you arrive at the latter from the definition of matrix norms and the definition of the vector norm $\| \circ \|_1$?

Comment: Please explain how you get $\sum_{i = 1}^{M} \sum_{j = 1}^{N} |a_{i,j}|$. Knowing that will help us find your mistake.

Comment: At the moment I can only remind you the $1$-norm is used on the domain AND range. Take all vectors with $\|x\|_1=1$. Which of them has the largest $\|Ax\|_1$? That number is $\|A\|_1$

Comment: @Daron See for example this -- http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/algebra/node12.html

Comment: Yes I am familiar with the definition. How do you arrive at $\|A\|_1=\sum_{i = 1}^{M} \sum_{j = 1}^{N} |a_{i,j}|$?

Comment: The same way they did :) Used the definition for the p-norm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{aligned}
\|A\|_1
&=\max_{x\ne0}\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_1}\\
&=\max_{x\ne0}\frac{\left\|A\sum_j x_je_j\right\|_1}{\|x\|_1}\\
&=\max_{x\ne0}\frac{\left\|\sum_j x_jAe_j\right\|_1}{\|x\|_1}\\
&\le\max_{x\ne0}\frac{\sum_j |x_j|\|Ae_j\|_1}{\|x\|_1}\\
&\le\max_{x\ne0}\frac{\left(\max_j\|Ae_j\|_1\right)\sum_j |x_j|}{\|x\|_1}\\
&=\max_{x\ne0}\frac{\left(\max_j\|Ae_j\|_1\right)\|x\|_1}{\|x\|_1}\\
&=\max_j\|Ae_j\|_1\\
&=\max_j\sum_i|a_{ij}|.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Why did you start like you did? Why $\max_{x \neq 0}$? The definition of $|| x||_1$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i|$ -- there is no max involved in that? So if you put its definition into the matrix subordinate norm definition, I still do not see how a max gets involved?

Comment: I know that if someone can explain me that part, your answer is perfect...

Comment: @noflow Every induced norm is defined in the this way, i.e. given a vector norm $\|x\|_v$ (the subscript is just a notation, not a number) on a vector space $V$, the operator norm $\|A\|_M$ of a linear operator $A$ on $V$ induced by the vector norm $\|\cdot\|_v$ is defined as $\|A\|_M=\sup\{\|Ax\|_v/\|x\|_v: 0\ne x\in V\}$. Since $Ax/\|x\|_v=Au$ where $u=x/\|x\|_v$ is a unit vector w.r.t. the norm $\|\cdot\|_v$, the previous definition is equivalent to $\|A\|_M=\sup\{\|Au\|_v:\|u\|_v=1\}$. When $\dim V<\infty$, the unit sphere is compact. Therefore you can replace $\sup$ by $\max$.

Comment: Finally I understand!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THanks!

Comment: Now that I look at it again: How can you say that what you ended up with is the definition with you used $\leq$ in the derivation?

Comment: @noflow I don't understand your question. If you mean why I prove only an inequality but not the reverse inequality, it's because the reverse inequality (i.e. $\|A\|_1=\max_{\|x\|_1=1}\|Ax\|_1\ge\max_j\|Ae_j\|_1$) is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

**Same Notation for Different Norms.**

The Wikipedia source uses this notation

$$\|A\|_1 = \sup\{\|Ax\|_1:\|x\|=1\}$$

This is called the **operator norm** when both domain and range carry the $1$-norm. Under this notation it can be shown $\|A\|_1 =$ the largest column sum.

The http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu source uses the definition $$\|A\|_p =p\text{-norm of }A \text{ if you treat is at a vector of length = #entries}.$$

The second source has $\|A\|_1 = \sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|$ by definition.

These are different objects. For example consider the $d \times d$ identity matrix. The operator norm is $1$ but in the second notation the norm is $d$.

Comment: Ah okay. Can you then please help showing that $|| A ||_1$ = the largest column sum? I do not see why it ends up being that. I am in the vector norm $|| \circ ||_1$ there is not even a max function involved?

Comment: Hint: The $j$ from $\max_{1 \leq j \leq M} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} |a_{i,j}|$ is the value we get if $x$ is the $j$-th unit vector.

Comment: I am sorry, I still cannot see how $\sum_{i = 1}^{M} \sum_{j = 1}^{N} |a_{i,j} u_j|$ should result in the expression using the max function :(